# Asserting two floats are equal

Tags: python, floating-point, assert

The following code gives an AssertionError in the last line.
However both values are printed as `10.0833333333`.

```
p = [0,1,2,3,4,6,2,2,4,1,2,4]
cell11 = p[0:3]
cell12 = p[3:6]
cell21 = p[6:9]
cell22 = p[9:12]

x11 = sum(cell11)/float(3)
x12 = sum(cell12)/float(3)
x21 = sum(cell21)/float(3)
x22 = sum(cell22)/float(3)
x1dot = (x11+x12)/float(2)
x2dot = (x21+x22)/float(2)
xdot1 = (x11+x21)/float(2)
xdot2 = (x12+x22)/float(2)
xdotdot = (x1dot+x2dot)/float(2)
assert(xdotdot == (xdot1+xdot2)/float(2))
n=3
x11diff = ((x11-xdotdot) - (x1dot-xdotdot) - (xdot1-xdotdot))**2
x12diff = ((x12-xdotdot) - (x1dot-xdotdot) - (xdot2-xdotdot))**2
x21diff = ((x21-xdotdot) - (x2dot-xdotdot) - (xdot1-xdotdot))**2
x22diff = ((x22-xdotdot) - (x2dot-xdotdot) - (xdot2-xdotdot))**2
ssaxb = n*(x11diff+x12diff+x21diff+x22diff)
print str(ssaxb)
print str(10+(1/float(12)))
assert(ssaxb == 10+(1/float(12)))
```

Are `ssaxb` and `10+(1/float(12))` somehow stored as slightly different values?

Comment: don't convert to `str()` prior to printing and you will see the `float`s are different

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html

Comment: @Chris_Rands But OP is not checking str values. It is just used while printing

Comment: @Chris_Rands actually they look the same even without the `str()`

Comment: @mad_ exactly, read what i wrote again. `print(ssaxb, 10+(1/float(12)))` > `10.083333333333329 10.083333333333334`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Chris_Rands printing the values will give you the reason why assert statement is failing as float values are different

```
import numpy as np

print(ssaxb, 10+(1/float(12)))  #(10.08333333333333, 10.083333333333334)

assert(np.isclose(ssaxb, 10+(1/float(12))))

assert(round(ssaxb,7),round(10+(1/float(12)),7))
```

Comment: Reason for downvoting, please?

Comment: 1. numpy is not otherwise mentioned so should use `math.isclose`  2. don't answer obvious dupes, just close vote.